# Bootstrap 4 carousel wrap issue for multi item display

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am playing around with bootstrap 4 carousels and was looking at this code tutorial https://www.codeply.com/go/EIOtI7nkP8. I wanted to try stopping the carousel from recycling through the same slides and stop when it goes through all of the slide. I looked at the document for bootstrap 4 on carousels and it said to use data-wrap and set it to false.

So all I changed was this:

```
<div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-wrap="false" data-ride="carousel">
```

But when i tried setting it to false the prev works however clicking on the next it will still keep on going after the last item is shown. Not really sure why this is happening and any suggestion would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue causing this was because it generates 6 carousel-item which contains all the images and although it wont wrap around it will go through all of the carousel item the last of which is the image 6.

So the solution is not the greatest but it does work. It will make the prev and next invisible when the last image within the carousel-item is visible on the slide. But that doesn't necessary mean it's the last carousel-item. The weak point of this solution is that for my math the number of slide has to be statically set. I couldn't figure out any other way to get the number of visible slides that is shown on screen dynamically. If anyone has any suggestions or better solution feel free to post!

My solution is here https://www.codeply.com/p/gTir2SytzH

```
$('#recipeCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', checkSlideWrap);  //for when user click on slides
$('#recipeCarousel').ready(checkSlideWrap);   //for when loading the page so the prev is not displaying
function checkSlideWrap()
{
  var divLength = $('div.carousel-item').length;
  var slides;
  if ($(window).width() >= 992 )
      slides = 3;
  else if ($(window).width() >= 768 )
      slides = 3;
  else
      slides = 1;   

  /*  hide the left and right controls when the carousel is showing the first/last slides */
  var $this = $('#recipeCarousel');
  if ($('.carousel-inner .carousel-item:first').hasClass('active')) {
      // Hide left arrow
      $this.children('.carousel-control-prev.carousel-control').hide();
      // But show right arrow
      $this.children('.carousel-control-next.carousel-control').show();
  } else if ($('.carousel-inner .carousel-item:gt(' + (slides - 1 - divLength) + ')').hasClass('active')) {
      // Hide right arrow
      $this.children('.carousel-control-next.carousel-control').hide();
      // But show left arrow
      $this.children('.carousel-control-prev.carousel-control').show();
  } else {
      $this.children('.carousel-control').show();
  }
}
```